# save mysql query field in a rails accessor

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, accessor

I have a MySQL table with 2 fields: `id`, `name`
I have to do a query like this:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       5 AS tot
FROM   examples
```

in rails I have a model for this table:

```
def Example < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessor :tot
end
```

If I try do execute this:

```
Example.select("examples.*, 5 as tot")
```

the variable tot of model is null for each row.

Why?

How I can assign the value of an not existent column in a model' s variable?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you might want to start by checking what the SQL prints out.

```
Example.select("examples.*, 5 as tot").to_sql
```

That will inspect to see what you are actually doing, from there you can see what is going on.

And out of curiousity how come you can't just do this, I am just confused on what you are trying accomplish above

```
tot = Example.select("examples.*, 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `attr_accessor :tot` from model